# (Concrete) mathematical aspects of programming

Tags: discrete-mathematics, soft-question, computer-science

It is often said that progamming is mathematics as it "makes use" of "discrete mathematics".

However, I would like to ask a more concrete question:

> what are the concepts of a programming language (for instance, let us
>   consider C, which is the only one I know) that have a "mathematical
>   equivalent"?

I would say for example that arrays are "equivalent" in some sense to vectors of $R^{n}$ and that multidimensional arrays are equivalent to matrices (does this sound right?). But what is, say, the "equivalent" of a pointer (if any)?

Comment: arrays and so on are just the _very_ basic tools of programming. One of the bigger Chunks is Graph theory and basically everything in relation to what Turing did.
Languages. Machines. Many more stuff.
Everything mathematical concepts, that can be sorted under the main term “Discrete maths”, but that term is very broad.

Comment: Also consider the logic gates which altogether allow the 1's and 0's to turn into something useful. Modulus is used in counting these and performing operations, and is also used to convert them into easier-to-read hexadecimal (mod 16) notation, which pops up from time to time when you run into a low-level error.

Comment: @Lukas I should point out that I *am* interested in the basic tools of programming in this question and not in the great topics of computer science.

Comment: Did it say programming? I am sorry, I must have misread.

Comment: There are some here who know more about it than I do, but a fairly important analogy exists between the datatypes of a programming language and the functors of category theory in math.  This is quite apparent in the Haskell programming language, but I believe the "equivalent" of a pointer (as you've asked) needs the machinery of category theory to explicate.

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are not matrices. They look the same, but they are semantically different. A matrix can be respresented as an array, but not all arrays are matrices.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you clarify that?

Comment: In the random access memory model you can think of pointers as indices of some very (in theory infinitely) large array, perhaps groupped for your convenience. If you want to look at connection between programming languages and math then start with semantics (operational and denotational), these tools provide a theoretical tools for working with actual languages. Other notions are usually much more disconnected from "metal" and don't even recognize differences between things like Java and Python, it is often enough to know that some formalism is Turing-complete and there it ends.